# Singleton SessionFactory in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, singleton, sessionfactory

I have started using `Hibernate` recently, but this question is confusing me. I have seen that `Session Factory` can be created multiple times if we have multiple datasources. But at the same time I have read that `sessionFactory` implements `singleton` too. Doesn't this contradict??

Comment: It is Singleton and It is one per data source. It is singleton you can create One sessionfactory for one datasource, you can not use the same instance for other datasources (i.e Single Instance)

Comment: Thanks @Pragnani. But usually when we make a class Singleton, we ensure that in any case there wont be other instance of that class, but this statement makes it singleton conditionally. 

Does this makes SessionFactory  a Complete Singleton Class???

Comment: It is not singleton per class loader, but it is singleton per data source.

Answer (score -1):

```
//use singleton hibernateUtil.java class
package com.onlinetutorialspoint.config;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtility {
public static SessionFactory factory;
//to disallow creating objects by other classes.

    private HibernateUtility() {
    }
//maling the Hibernate SessionFactory object as singleton

    public static synchronized SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

        if (factory == null) {
            factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").
                    buildSessionFactory();
        }
        return factory;
    }
}
```